# Is sample code for atomic_compare_exchange_weak at cppreference correct?

Tags: c++, c++11

At http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange, the following example code is presented as an example use of `std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak`:

```
void append(list* s, node* n)
{
    node* head;
    do {
        head = s->head;
        n->next = head;
    } while(! std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(s->head, head, n));
}
```

My understanding is that this has the the effect of comparing `*(s->head)` with `head`, when what I believe is desired is to compare `s->head` with `head`.  Should the first argument to `std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak` in this example be `&(s->head)`, or am I missing something?

UPDATE: The spec for `std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak` says:

```
bool atomic_compare_exchange_weak(volatile A* object, C * expected, C desired) noexcept;
bool atomic_compare_exchange_weak(A* object, C * expected, C desired) noexcept;
```

> *Effects*: Atomically, compares the contents of the memory
>   pointed to by object...for equality with that in expected...

I took this to mean that `*object` was compared with `expected`, but further research suggests that the actual meaning is that `*object` is compared with `*expected` (i.e., that "in `expected`" means "pointed to by `expected`").  This would imply that the answer to my original question is "no, there is no need to take the address of `s->head` in the example code at cppreference". But the fact that `object` must point to a `std::atomic<T>` and expected must point to a `T` makes it hard for me to figure out how to correct the code at cppreference so that it will compile.  We want to compare the head of the list with a copy of the head of the list, but if the head of the list is of type `std::atomic<T>*`, the copy would have to be of type `T*` if the call to `std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak` is to compile, and I can't find a way to assign a `std::atomic<T>*` to a `T*` without a `reinterpret_cast`. Even then, the third parameter to `std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak` would need to be of type `T`, but the example at cppreference shows both the second and third parameters to be of the same type. This suggests to me that the example at cppreference is broken. I tried to fix it, but I was stymied by the need to use a `reinterpret_cast` that just feels wrong.

Interestingly, in my attempts to figure this stuff out, I checked out the [msdn page for `std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh874646.aspx), and I was dismayed to see that that page displays the prototypes for `std::atomic_compare_exchange_*strong*`!

Can somebody post plausible code that uses `std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak` to insert a node at the front of a singly-linked list?  There's no need to worry about the ABA problem or do anything fancy. I'd just like to see skeletal code that compiles.

Comment: Is `node` supposed to be an atomic object?

Comment: That's the complete code snippet from cppreference, but I don't think it affects the answer to my question.

Comment: The code is nonsense. The first argument to `atomic_compare_exchange_weak` should be a pointer to an object of an atomic type; the second argument should be a pointer to an object of the corresponding value type; the third argument is an object (not a pointer) of the corresponding value type.

Comment: As to the MSDN problem, the signatures of `atomic_compare_exchange_weak` and `atomic_compare_exchange_strong` are the same; only the name is different. So this is just a cut-and-paste error, a common occurrence in the atomics stuff, since so much of it looks alike. That aside, the documentation is correct.

Comment: I removed the example for now (it's a wiki, after all), since, indeed, it was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct example would be:

```
struct list {
    std::atomic<node*> head;
};

...

void append(list* s, node* n)
{
    node* head;
    do {
        head = s->head;
        n->next = head;
    } while (!std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&(s->head), &head, n));
    // or while (!s->head.compare_exchange_weak(head, n));
}
```

The `list::head` would need to be a `std::atomic` object, unless you want to deal with undefined behavior. The platform in question might need some or all of the `std::atomic` stuff to be implemented using locks. Therefore, `std::atomic<T*>` might include additional members and `reinterpret_cast<std::atomic<T*>*>` would be the case where UB means that your program crashes.

Comment: This compiles, once the appropriate skeleton is built around it. A [compilable example](http://ideone.com/eZnylZ) is available at IDEOne. I did not test the sample code to make sure it works, but at least it compiles.